# Dice loss variations (mean, maximal per block)

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I use the next simple implementation of dice loss:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
  y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
  y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
  intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
  return (2. * intersection + 1.) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + 1.)

def MyModelLoss(y_true, y_pred):
  # shape: samples, width, height, 2 classes (0..1)
  return 1 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

I want to try the next variations:

- mean per batch (current implementation don't take into consideration the internal structure of results... I'm not sure, but maybe mean dice coefficient would be more relevant)
- calculate dice coefficient for 32*32 blocks and take minimal... Again, I'm not sure, but maybe it would be more relevant.

I tried to implement mean loss by simple `dice_coef(y_true, y_pred) / y_true.shape[0]` (which isn't correct, I know), but even this cause exception `ValueError: None values not supported.`. I understand that Keras trying to find out information about loss function and calling it on the empty batch, but what would be correct implementation than?

---

Partially solved in next way:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
  #considering shape (batch, image_size, image_size, classes)
  axis = [1, 2]
  intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=axis)
  sums = K.sum(y_true, axis=axis) + K.sum(y_pred, axis=axis)
  # standard dice
  dice = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (sums + smooth)
  # min dice over the classes
  minClassDice = K.min(dice, axis=-1)
  # mean over all samples in the batch
  return K.mean(minClassDice, axis=-1)
```

I'm not sure that it correctly works (I could confuse axis), but the accuracy of the model is greatly improved. But there is a drawback: the network can "stuck", because of `min` may hide noticeable changes.

Comment: How are you getting `y_true` and `y_pred`?

Comment: em.... Keras pass them to loss function on each epoch of training